# Check for Named Event

Tags: c++, windows, event-handling

I have a process that creates a named event, using `::CreateEvent`.

In my process, I want to check whether the event exists or not, but I don't want to create the event in case it doesn't exist.

How can I do it?

I can do it like this, but then the event will be created in case it doesn't exist:

```
HANDLE hEvent;
hEvent= ::CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, _T("MyEvent"));
if (::GetLastError() != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
{
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OpenEvent` does **not** create the event if it doesn't already exist, so your code already almost does what you want. You need to check the event handle for `NULL` before checking the error code:

```
HANDLE hEvent;
hEvent= ::OpenEvent(FALSE, FALSE, _T("MyEvent"));
if (!hEvent) // event does not already exist, or other problem
{
   .......
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake. I ment to use "CreateEvent" and not "OpenEvent". "OpenEvent" doesn't work for me at all, it returns NULL in any case, even in a case the event exists.. I edited my question.

Comment: Check the error code. If the event exists, but `OpenEvent` returns `NULL` then there is another problem. This is probably a permissions error --- if the event is created by another process then you may not have the right permissions to access it, especially if the other process is a service or other system process, or run by another user.

Answer (score 1):

```
CString csHandleName = "hEvent";
int nHandleinc(0);
HANDLE hHandleEvent = NULL;
while(!hHandleEvent)
{
    csHandleName.Format("hEvent%d",nHandleinc);
    hHandleEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,false,csHandleName);
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ) 
    {
    CloseHandle( hHandleEvent ); 
    hHandleEvent = NULL;
    }
    nHandleinc++;
}
```